# Rails v4 with Raspberry Pi

Tags: ruby-on-rails, raspberry-pi, thin

I have Raspberry Pi with Pidora OS. I am using:
-ruby (1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [armv6hl-linux]
-rails (4.0.0)
When I am trying to run rails I get error:

```
    => Booting Thin
    => Rails 4.0.0 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
    => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
    => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
    Exiting
            /usr/local/share/gems/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/railtie/configuration.rb:95:in `method_missing': undefined method `active_record' for #<Rails::Application::Configuration:0x28cf0b0> (NoMethodError)
    from /home/user1/RubyOnRails/site1/config/environments/development.rb:23:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/share/gems/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:24:in `class_eval'
    from /usr/local/share/gems/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:24:in `configure'
    from /home/user1/RubyOnRails/site1/config/environments/development.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/share/gems/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
    from /usr/local/share/gems/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `block in require'
    from /usr/local/share/gems/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:213:in `load_dependency'
    from /usr/local/share/gems/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
    from /usr/local/share/gems/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:591:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
    from /usr/local/share/gems/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:590:in `each'
    from /usr/local/share/gems/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:590:in `block in <class:Engine>'
    from /usr/local/share/gems/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /usr/local/share/gems/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /usr/local/share/gems/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /usr/share/ruby/tsort.rb:150:in `block in tsort_each'
    from /usr/share/ruby/tsort.rb:183:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /usr/share/ruby/tsort.rb:210:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /usr/share/ruby/tsort.rb:219:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /usr/share/ruby/tsort.rb:209:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /usr/local/share/gems/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'
    from /usr/local/share/gems/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
    from /usr/share/ruby/tsort.rb:203:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /usr/share/ruby/tsort.rb:182:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /usr/share/ruby/tsort.rb:180:in `each'
    from /usr/share/ruby/tsort.rb:180:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /usr/share/ruby/tsort.rb:148:in `tsort_each'
    from /usr/local/share/gems/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /usr/local/share/gems/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:215:in `initialize!'
    from /usr/local/share/gems/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
    from /home/user1/RubyOnRails/site1/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/user1/RubyOnRails/site1/config.ru:3:in `require'
    from /home/user1/RubyOnRails/site1/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
    from /usr/local/share/gems/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
    from /usr/local/share/gems/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
    from /home/user1/RubyOnRails/site1/config.ru:in `new'
    from /home/user1/RubyOnRails/site1/config.ru:in `<main>'
    from /usr/local/share/gems/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
    from /usr/local/share/gems/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
    from /usr/local/share/gems/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
    from /usr/local/share/gems/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:277:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
    from /usr/local/share/gems/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:199:in `app'
    from /usr/local/share/gems/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:48:in `app'
    from /usr/local/share/gems/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:314:in `wrapped_app'
    from /usr/local/share/gems/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:75:in `start'
    from /usr/local/share/gems/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:78:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/share/gems/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:73:in `tap'
    from /usr/local/share/gems/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:73:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

My Gemfile :
        
source 'https://rubygems.org'
        gem 'thin', '1.5.1'
        gem 'rails', '4.0.0'
        gem 'sqlite3'

My gems:
        *** LOCAL GEMS ***

```
    actionmailer (4.0.0, 3.2.14, 3.2.8)
    actionpack (4.0.0, 3.2.14, 3.2.8)
    activemodel (4.0.0, 3.2.14, 3.2.8)
    activerecord (4.0.0, 3.2.14, 3.2.8)
    activerecord-deprecated_finders (1.0.3)
    activeresource (4.0.0, 3.2.14, 3.2.8)
    activesupport (4.0.0, 3.2.14, 3.2.8)
    addressable (2.3.5)
    arel (4.0.0, 3.0.2)
    atomic (1.1.12, 1.1.10)
    backports (3.3.3)
    bigdecimal (1.2.1)
    builder (3.1.4, 3.0.4)
    bundler (1.3.5)
    coffee-rails (4.0.0, 3.2.2)
    coffee-script (2.2.0)
    coffee-script-source (1.6.3)
    daemons (1.1.9)
    diff-lcs (1.2.4, 1.1.3)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    eventmachine (1.0.3)
    excon (0.25.3)
    execjs (1.4.0)
    heroku (2.40.0)
    heroku-api (0.3.14)
    hike (1.2.3)
    i18n (0.6.4)
    io-console (0.4.2)
    jbuilder (1.5.0)
    journey (1.0.4)
    jquery-rails (3.0.4)
    json (1.8.0)
    launchy (2.3.0)
    mail (2.5.4, 2.4.4)
    mime-types (1.23)
    mini_portile (0.5.1)
    minitest (4.7.5)
    multi_json (1.7.8, 1.7.7)
    multipart-post (1.2.0)
    net-http-persistent (2.9)
    netrc (0.7.7)
    nosql (0.0.2)
    polyglot (0.3.3)
    rack (1.5.2, 1.4.5)
    rack-cache (1.2)
    rack-ssl (1.3.3)
    rack-test (0.6.2)
    rails (4.0.0, 3.2.14, 3.2.8)
    rails-observers (0.1.2)
    railties (4.0.0, 3.2.14, 3.2.8)
    rake (10.1.0)
    rake-compiler (0.9.1)
    rdoc (3.12.2)
    rest-client (1.6.7)
    rspec (2.14.1)
    rspec-core (2.14.4)
    rspec-expectations (2.14.0)
    rspec-mocks (2.14.2)
    rspec-spies (2.1.4)
    rubygems-update (2.0.6)
    rubyzip (0.9.9)
    sass (3.2.10, 3.2.9)
    sass-rails (4.0.0, 3.2.6)
    sdoc (0.3.20)
    specific_install (0.2.3)
    sprockets (2.10.0, 2.2.2, 2.1.3)
    sprockets-rails (2.0.0)
    sqlite3 (1.3.7)
    thin (1.5.1)
    thor (0.18.1, 0.14.6)
    thread_safe (0.1.2)
    tilt (1.4.1)
    treetop (1.4.14)
    turbolinks (1.3.0)
    tzinfo (0.3.37)
    uglifier (2.1.2)
    vulcan (0.8.2)
```

Does anyone can help me to find where problem is?

Comment: Hope you have done 'bundle update' & 'bundle install' . Can you show us your config/application.rb file. Does it have "require 'rails/all'"

Comment: 'bundle update' & 'bundle install' doesn't change anything. application.rb:
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

require 'rails/all'

# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(:default, Rails.env)

module Site1
  class Application < Rails::Application

  end
end

Answer (score 0):

Did you run rake db:migrate? Seems like you need to